# UWP application hangs when converting a canvas to image

Tags: c#, uwp

I trying to convert the canvas in UWP to image (`RenderTargetBitmap`). I have two options to return the image to end user.

1. `StorageFile`
2. `System.IO.Stream`

When I use the storage file everything works as expected. **But when I use a memory stream, the application hangs**. I have created a simple sample to reproduce the issue.

```
<Grid Background="White" Name ="Main_Grid">
    <Button Content="UIToImage" Margin="141,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="UIToImageAsync"></Button>
</Grid>


private async void UIToImageAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //Pick a folder                     
        var folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        var storageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("Output.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        //using (var inputImgStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())//this works
        using (var inputImgStream = new MemoryStream())//this doesn't work
        {
            //Draw a line
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path path = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path();
            DrawShape(path);

            //The canvas to hold the above shape - line
            var canvas = new Canvas();
            //Add canvas to the grid in XAML
            Main_Grid.Children.Add(canvas);
            canvas.Children.Add(path);


            //Draw the canvas to the image
            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = null;

            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
            {
                bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
                canvas.Height = 800;
                canvas.Width = 1380;
                canvas.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform { X = 1, Y = 100
                };
            });


            //Render a bitmap image
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,async () => 
            {
                await bitmap.RenderAsync(canvas, 1380, 800);
            });

            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, inputImgStream.AsRandomAccessStream());// I suspect passing the MemoryStream is the issue. While 'StorageFile' is used there are no issues.

            IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight,
                DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
                pixelBuffer.ToArray());

            await encoder.FlushAsync(); // The application hangs here
        }
    }    

    private void DrawShape(Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Path path)
    {
        PathGeometry lineGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        PathFigure lineFigure = new PathFigure();
        LineSegment lineSegment = new LineSegment();

        lineFigure.StartPoint = new Point(100, 100);
        lineSegment.Point = new Point(200, 200);

        lineFigure.Segments.Add(lineSegment);
        path.Data = lineGeometry;
        SolidColorBrush strokeBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
        path.Stroke = strokeBrush;
        path.StrokeThickness = 5;
        lineGeometry.Figures.Add(lineFigure);
    }
```

Can anyone point me out about what causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really seems that using a simple `MemoryStream` with `AsRandomAccessStream` does not workm, although I am not sure about the reason. Instead, you can use `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`, which will work as expected.

There is however another problem, which might be a source of problems, or at least it caused it to crash on my machine:

```
//Render a bitmap image
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
   CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () => 
   {
      await bitmap.RenderAsync(canvas, 1380, 800);
   });
```

Although it seems that the `await` will wait for the `RenderAsync` call to finish, it unfortunately does not. The second parameter is only a `DispatchedHandler`. This delegate has the following signature:

```
public delegate void DispatchedHandler()
```

As you can see there is no `Task` return value. That means it will create just a `async void` lambda. The lambda will start running and when it reaches the `RenderAsync`, it will start executing it, but hte `RunAsync`'s `await` may (and most likely **will**) finish **before** the `RunAsync` does. So it is likely, that you will start to execute the `bitmap.GetPixelAsync` while the `bitmap` is still completely empty.

To fix this, you should move the code inside the lambda:

```
//Render a bitmap image
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
{
    await bitmap.RenderAsync(canvas, 1380, 800);
    using (var inputImgStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream()) //this doesn't work
    {                        
        var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId,
            inputImgStream
                ); // I suspect passing the MemoryStream is the issue. While 'StorageFile' is used there are no issues.

        IBuffer pixelBuffer = await bitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine($"Capacity = {pixelBuffer.Capacity}, Length={pixelBuffer.Length}");

        var pixelArray = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
        encoder.SetPixelData(
            BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
            BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
            (uint) bitmap.PixelWidth,
            (uint) bitmap.PixelHeight,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
            pixelArray
        );

        await encoder.FlushAsync(); // The application hangs here
    }
});
```

As you can see, you must also move the `using` block for the stream inside the lambda, because if it were outside, the same fate would happen - the `using` might `Dispose` of the stream before the `RenderAsync` finished.